# Is it possible to move gear on a shaft in one moment and in the other allow it to rotate freely?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Before I describe the problem I would just like to say that I'm no engineer this is my hobby, all I know is from google or if someone told me or from books. Something obvious to you may not be obvious to me. Thanks

I want to move a gear with the shaft like they were one in one moment and in the other I want to stop the gear using clutch brake while continuing to rotate the shaft.

One way to achieve this is using air bearings which would be the perfect solution if they weren't so impractical because of the required compressor and other parts.

Second solution would be to use two clutches. One to connect the gear to shaft and another clutch to brake the gear when the first one is not connected but I don't want to use more than one clutch pack because they are expensive.

Third solution is to use sync cone but that is much slower than clutch and that is why I don't want to use it.

Fourth solution which I found is using a shaft mounted brake to lock the gear with the shaft but I'm not sure if this would count as a clutch brake and if it would lower the efficiency of the system as whole.

So my question would be is there a way to achieve the problem described without using more breaks or clutches (if shaft mounted brake wouldn't count as a break then that is also OK)? The perfect solution would be a bearing which I could "turn off" and let it rotate with the shaft but I'm not sure if something like that exists.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info. Tell us exactly what you are doing and provide the specs on how fast and how frequently the gear needs to be toggled. There are hydraulic coupler devices that may be better suited to your needs. Does the gear need to free spin in both directions relative to the shaft, or just one direction? does the shaft have to transmit torque in both directions, or just one?

Comment: A small marine tranny such as Hurth or Twin Disc can be had for a couple thou.

Comment: Ok sorry. I am designing some sort of a transmission so the gear would need to be toggled couple of times in a minute. It actually doesn't need to free spin it just needs to be disconnected and when it is I would use clutch brakes to stop it so you could say it only needs to spin in one direction. The shaft transmits torque only in one direction.

Comment: I think the A/C clutch from Solar Mike and a separate brake would be your best bet. I've seen a cheap lawnmower that had a single clutch/brake pedal, and even it split that motion into two separate devices. (The "clutch" simply pulled a spring tensioner away from a belt, and the brake was a mini disc brake on the transmission output. My brother and I geared it way up to make a 5-speed manual go-kart...and learned a few things about designing to a price point.)

Comment: If you do use separate devices, keep an eye on timing.  You probably don't want to drag both at the same time because of differing activation / deactivation times.  The lawnmower solved that problem by inherently fine-controlling position, but you can't do that with on/off electrical devices.

Comment: I will be using separate brake to stop the gear from rotating in any case. I was just looking for other solutions on how to move the gear with input. And yes I know I have to work out the timings but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Okay, try looking at detent clutches (aka ball clutches). They are a type of overload disconnect. All you have to do is apply the brake. When you release the brake, the clutch will reengage automatically. [link](http://clutches-torque-limiters.herseyclutch.com/viewitems/spring-detent-clutches/model-sxt-spring-detent-clutches-2)

Comment: there are also combo types - [link](http://machiii.com/Products/Clutch-Brakes/Stop-Start-Shaft-Clutch-Brakes-Integral-Double-Single-Sprocket.asp)

Comment: That would be perfect. I just have one more question. Will those clutches be able to handle high torque? I can see that they are also used as safety clutches to release when torque is too high. Can that limit be put to something like 750 Nm?

Comment: To clarify I want tge transmission to have high torque capacity. Is that affected by detent clutch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use a electromagnetic clutch, often used on car a/c compressors to disconnect them when not needed.

When engaged they drive and  freewheel when not energised.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, for example, in an automatic transmission it is viewed as a bad thing to have many clutches and brakes. Would an electromagnetic clutch count like other clutches which are used in compound planetary gears to move and stop certain parts? Real life example would be ZF 8HP transmission uses 5 clutches in total. If they added electromagnetic clutch to their transmission would it count to total used?

Comment: Case international had electro-hydraulic clutches.. why is it important to count them? You need to work out if it will work in your design - which is not clear by the way.

Comment: Well, it's not important to count but it would be important to keep the number as low as possible. And yes it would work this is final piece of the puzzle so to say.

Comment: @DominikSerbinek if this helped, you should accept the answer or vote for it...

Comment: It helped I just wanted to ask you more about it. I upvoted when you answeredbut since I have less than 15 reputation it doesn't show

Comment: Upvoted your question... soon be there.